# Is there uniqueness for linear but second order partial differential equation

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have a second order PDE like $F_{xx}(x,t) = F(x,t),$ and $F(x,0) = f(x),$ where $f(x) \in L^2.$

In this case, how do we define "uniqueness" of the solution? Would it be of a particular function, or rather, a set of functions that is instead unique? What suitable space does $F$ belong to to maintain uniqueness of the solution?

Comment: 1) That is an ODE, not a PDE. 2) $f(x) \in L^{2}$ is meaningless without specifying the domain of $x$. 3) For a PDE to have a unique solution means that there is one and only one solution that satisfies the PDE _and_ associated data. If I understand your second question correctly, it is a single, particular function. 4) If I understand your last question correctly, that entirely depends on the PDE; see [functional analysis](http://www.math.utoronto.ca/almut/Brezis.pdf).